# BundleId is not the same as AppId

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to submit my first app to the app store and I am stuck trying to create my archive in xcode 6 - my AppID is of the format `com.XXXXXXX.prefix` but my bundleID is missing the `com` i.e. it is `XXXXXXX.prefix`.

I get an error

> no matching provisioning profiles found

and a statement that the AppId does not match the bundle identifier.  (The error message says xcode can fix the issue but it never does.)

There are lots of answers around but I just can't figure out how to make my bundle identifier match the AppId.

Thanks for any help - I've been stuck for ages on this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it out from another person's answer.  (Thanks Jon Schneider)

The BundleID in the info.plist file must = The BundleId on the iTunes Connect website at My Apps>[your app]>More>About This App.

That's it!